# Fetch hierarchy data using FetchXML in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml, dynamics-365

I need to create a FetchXML request that retrieve every division and it's subdivisions from dynamics 365.

**Expected result**

```
Div
  -- Div1
     -- Div1-1
     -- Div1-2
  -- Div2
     -- Div2-1
     -- Div2-2
  -- Div2
  -- Div3
  -- Div4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a dynamic hierarchy of divisions, that is not possible using FetchXML.

Comment: you probably should update this answer, since it's the accepted but now out of date. This answer ranks way up the google algorithm on "fetch query heirarchical" -- which got one of my junior devs kind of confused because they recognized you as an MVP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be able to get away with retrieving all divisions and sorting by name.

The FetchXML for that would be:

```
<fetch distinct="false" > 
    <entity name='new_division'>
        <order attribute="new_name" descending="false" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Please note that in the latest versions of CRM have added the ability to do FetchXML hierarchical queries with the following operators:
[image: FetchXml Hierarchy operators]

For more information [see this article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817893.aspx)